# How to: Two horizontal Barplots "on top of eachother"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with: Fail [3,3,3,1] and Pass [50,40,50,10]

I just want to make a barplot of Fail and Pass

```
b_f <- barplot(dat_record$Fail[1], horiz = TRUE, ylab = "FAIL", las = 2, col = "red", xlim = c(0,200))

b_p <- barplot(dat_record$Pass[2], horiz = TRUE, ylab = "PASS", las = 2, col = "green", xlim = c(0,200))
```

How can i put this two barplots on top of eachother in one graphic/diagram, like this:

[image]

And second question:

How can i do this properly with ggplot2? I tried it out, but i always failed with:

```
ggplot(dat_failpass, aes = (x = fail, fill = "red")+
geom_bar(position = "dodge")+
coord_flip()
```

Can someone answer me this two question or can you give me any tipps? I'm new into this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want just the first value of the vectors "Fail" and "Pass" value, this code chunk must plot what you want:

```
library(ggplot2)

fail = c(3, 3, 3, 1)
pass = c(50, 40, 50, 10)
df = data.frame(value = c(fail[1], pass[1]), label = c('Fail', 'Pass'))

ggplot(df, aes(x = label, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(y = 'Count') +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Let us know if this solution solved your problem.

Comment: Dear  rodolfoksveiga, almost. I just want to output the Fail[1] = 3 and Pass[1] = 50 and not the sum of all of this. That means: For Pass we should have 50 in the barplot and for Fail we should have an output of 3. I have a given dataframe with the mentioned input. I always have to take the first input of Fail and Pass.

Comment: Sure @Learning_CJ, I've got it wrong. I think now it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Using your data in this format, here the code for plot:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df <- structure(list(Fail = c(3, 3, 3, 1), Pass = c(50, 40, 50, 10)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Code:

```
#Reshape and plot
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  #Plot
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=value))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',fill='gray')+
  coord_flip()+
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]